# How to trigger a GH Actions workflow once a Slim CI job is completed (and successful)

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, dbt, dbt-cloud

We are currently running a linter for each of our CI builds within GitHub PRs. This linter, though, requires a dbt `manifest.json` which we can only build when the full dbt schemas are available in the PR schema.

We currently need to manually re-trigger the action workflow after dbt Cloud Slim CI is finished, since we have the `on` trigger as follows:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - main
    types: [opened, reopened, ready_for_review, synchronize]
```

And, as mentioned, the `manifest.json` is not yet built at the moment when the PR is e.g. `opened`.

Is there any way that we can trigger the workflow only once the Slim CI job (that is triggered by dbt Cloud) is actually completed, and therefore the `manifest.json` already built?

I've come across `on.check_run` and `on.status` for *Events that trigger workflows* (see [GH docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#status)), but not sure whether these can be used since, as specified in the docs: "*Note: This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch.*"

Comment: Do you have access to the dbt Cloud API? (requires a paid plan)

Comment: Yes, I do have access to the API

Comment: You can use a workflow that looks something like: PR triggers GH action -> Python script to trigger dbt Cloud run -> Download manifest.json -> continue checks.   [Here](https://jcdan3.medium.com/how-to-run-python-scripts-in-your-github-actions-caccac969b34) is a good example of how to run a script using Actions.

Comment: dbt Cloud is already running a Slim CI job based on state:modified+ .sql files on every pull request. The question was more on how to base my GH Actions workflow on that specific Slim Ci job being completed successfully.

Comment: Ah, I see. There do seem to be ways to use the Check Status API (example [action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/await-status-action)), so it looks like the short answer to your question is yes.

Personally, I'd still recommend triggering the dbt job via the Cloud API (i.e. disable the webhook in the app) so that you have more control over the workflow and a linear DAG.